# Same data, different results on discriminant analysis with MASS and caret

Tags: r, machine-learning, cross-validation, r-caret

A very brief question on predictive analysis in R.
Why are the cross-validated results obtained with the `MASS` package Linear Discriminant Analysis so different from the ones obtained with `caret`?

```
#simulate data
set.seed(4321)

training_data = as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(10000, sd = 12), 100, 10))
training_data$V1 = as.factor(sample(c(1,0), size = 100, replace = T))
names(training_data)[1] = 'outcome'

#MASS LDA
fit.lda_cv_MASS = lda(outcome~.
            , training_data
            , CV=T)
pred = fit.lda_cv_MASS$class
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, training_data$outcome)
```

This gives an accuracy of ~0.53

```
#caret interface LDA
lg.fit_cv_CARET = train(outcome ~ .
               , data=training_data
               , method="lda"
               , trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV")
              )
pred = predict(lg.fit_cv_CARET, training_data)
caret::confusionMatrix(pred, training_data$outcome)
```

Now this results in an accuracy of ~0.63.

I would have assumed they are identical since both use leave-one-out cross-validation.

Why are they different?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two points here, first is a mistake on your part and the other is a subtle difference.

point 1.

when you call predict on the caret train object you are in fact calling predict on a model fit on all the training data, hence the accuracy you get is not `LOOCV` but train accuracy. To get the re-sample accuracy you need just call:

```
lg.fit_cv_CARET$results
#output:
  parameter Accuracy       Kappa
1      none     0.48 -0.04208417
```

and not 0.63 which is just the train accuracy obtained when you call predict on the train data.

however this still does not match the 0.53 obtained by LDA. To understand why:

point 2. when fitting the model, `lda` also uses the argument `prior`:

> the prior probabilities of class membership. If unspecified, the class
>   proportions for the training set are used. If present, the
>   probabilities should be specified in the order of the factor levels

so `lda` with `CV = TRUE` uses the same prior as for the full train set. while `caret::train` uses the `prior` determined by the re-sample. For LOOCV this should not matter much, since the prior changes just a little bit, however your data has very low separation of classes, so the prior influences the posterior probability a bit more then usual. To prove this point use the same prior for both approaches:

```
fit.lda_cv_MASS <- lda(outcome~.,
                      training_data,
                      CV=T,
                      prior = c(0.5, 0.5))
pred = fit.lda_cv_MASS$class

lg.fit_cv_CARET <- train(outcome ~ .,
                         data=training_data,
                         method="lda",
                         trControl = trainControl(method = "LOOCV"),
                         prior = c(0.5, 0.5)
)

all.equal(lg.fit_cv_CARET$pred$pred, fit.lda_cv_MASS$class)
#output
TRUE

caret::confusionMatrix(pred, training_data$outcome)
#output
Confusion Matrix and Statistics

          Reference
Prediction  0  1
         0 27 25
         1 24 24

               Accuracy : 0.51           
                 95% CI : (0.408, 0.6114)
    No Information Rate : 0.51           
    P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.5401         

                  Kappa : 0.0192         
 Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.0000         

            Sensitivity : 0.5294         
            Specificity : 0.4898         
         Pos Pred Value : 0.5192         
         Neg Pred Value : 0.5000         
             Prevalence : 0.5100         
         Detection Rate : 0.2700         
   Detection Prevalence : 0.5200         
      Balanced Accuracy : 0.5096         

       'Positive' Class : 0 

lg.fit_cv_CARET$results
#output
  parameter Accuracy      Kappa
1      none     0.51 0.01921537
```

Comment: Good points (+1). I suggest you clarify exactly which `pred` you use in `confusionMatrix`, since it is defined 2 times in the OP.